# How to implement sentence-level log-likelihood in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, crf, log-likelihood

I want to implement the sentence-level log-likelihood as described in 
[Collobert et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.0398v1.pdf), p. 14.

To compute transition scores, I could use CRF, but I don't know how to integrate it in tensorflow. I thought about using 
[tf.contrib.crf.CrfForwardRnnCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.crf.html#CrfForwardRnnCell) to compute transition scores, but this class returns a **pair** of [batch_size, num_tags] matrices values containing the new alpha values and not as I would expect one [batch_size, num_tags, num_tags] tensor.

Does anyone has an example how to use CRF in tensorflow? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good example of using contrib.crf in TensorFlow is given here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/crf

It's worth noting that the SLL objective described in the paper Collobert et al. 2011 is slightly different than the CRF objective in that SLL lacks normalization (see Remark 4 on p. 16), but this shouldn't really matter in practice (I'd just use the CRF.)

Comment: note that this repo is not supported by TensorFlow https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7751

Comment: I think you mean Collobert at al. 2011

Comment: Unfortunately the link from you answer is no longer pointing to a public repository.